# Doctrine sql syntax for fetching a specific column data

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, doctrine-orm

How can I get only a selected items data from doctrine, here in my code I try to fetch only the `apartmentId`, but it returns all related data by finding it by the `$userId`. How can I get only and only `apartmentId`.

```
$selectData= "SELECT apartmentId FROM user_apartments WHERE userId = $userId";

$getData = $em->getConnection()->prepare($selectData); 
$getData->execute();

print_r($getData);
```

Answer (score 0):

The sql looks incorrect - think it should be more like:-

```
$selectData= "SELECT `apartmentId` 
    FROM `user_apartments` 
    WHERE `userId` = '$userId';";
```